# The post-traumatic stress of my last performance on the "Jimmy Fallon Show."

Tags: articles

"The post-traumatic stress of my last performance on the "Jimmy Fallon Show.""

Is "the" necessary in the sentence above (before the name of the show)?
Asking this because I've seen things like "Guests On Conan O'Brien's Show That Made Him Laugh Out Loud" (no definite article here)

Comment: Yes - in fact, it should be inside the inverted commas as a part of the title.

Comment: Which "The"  (this word appear twice in the quote.

Comment: Just made it clearer

Comment: There is no definite article in *Conan O'Brien's Show* because you cannot have both a possessive 's and the definite article (*the show* is ok, so is *Jimmy's show*, but *the Jimmy's show* is ungrammatical). But there would be nothing ungrammatical about *the Conan O'Brien show*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly complicated because there isn’t actually a show called “The Jimmy
Fallon Show.” I believe the show referred to is actually “The Tonight Show with Jimmy Fallon.” However, it is not unusual to refer to a show as “The (star’s name) Show,” even if that is not the official name, especially for talk shows.

The person has used “The Jimmy Fallon Show” as the name of the show, and even though this is an incorrect or informal version of the title, it is still effectively the name of the show, including the “the.” “The” is necessary because it is part of the “name,” and it should also be inside the quotation marks.

The correct name (The Tonight Show) also has “the” in it, so it would be necessary with the correct name as well - again, “the” is part of the name.